# Create Content Type with a Default Title

Tags: 7

How would for the Title of something to be default, static, unchanageable?

I've got a content type (plus others planned) that I plan on using as a data submittal for stuff similar to a "Quote of the Day" or "Create an Event for the Calendar" type content. I plan on keeping these "nodes" hidden for the most part and using views to view, edit, add, delete. The title will be mostly wasted space and unneeded.

How Can I do a Default, unchangeable Title for "Create" screen? Or... change a title for a content type to a different field type (Say... Date Field)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Automatic Nodetitles module](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) can do what you're looking for. When used in conjunction with the [Token module](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle), you have lots of options.

Comment: Right on the money... I had that downloaded but handn't tinkered with it yet. Thanks :)